# Run a workflow in Swift (Mac)

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoa, workflow, automator

**Hi everyone,**

I have a Workflow file that I'd like to run from a Swift Mac app. This is my current code:

```
    @IBAction func onChangeMode(_ sender: Any) {
    guard let workflowPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "wf", ofType: "workflow") else {
            print("resource not found")
            return
        }

        let workflowURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: workflowPath)
        do {
            try AMWorkflow.run(at:workflowURL, withInput: nil)
        } catch {
            print("Error: \(error)")
        }
    }
```

However, I keep getting this error:

> Error: Error Domain=com.apple.Automator Code=0 "Automator encountered an error running this workflow: “Sandboxed applications can not use Automator.framework to run workflows.”" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x600000cad8c0 {Error Domain=com.apple.Automator Code=0 "Sandboxed applications can not use Automator.framework to run workflows." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Sandboxed applications can not use Automator.framework to run workflows.}}, NSLocalizedDescription=Automator encountered an error running this workflow: “Sandboxed applications can not use Automator.framework to run workflows.”, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Sandboxed applications can not use Automator.framework to run workflows.}

How can I fix this? If anyone has a solution I'd be greatful - I'm new to Mac development.

**Thank you all so much, and I hope you're all doing well during this time.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must not use a sandbox for your app if you want to run workflows (that's what the error says!), so go to here:

[image]

And press on the circled "x" button. Note that apps without a sandbox can't be uploaded to the Mac App Store.